# Identity related to symmetric distribution

Tags: distributions, symmetry

Let $F$ be a symmetric (around $\frac{1}{2}$) cumulative distribution whose support is $[0,1]$. So, $F(x)=1-F(1-x),\forall x\in[0,1]$. Would this identity hold for any such $F$? 
$$\int^1_0(x-\frac{1}{2})F(x)(1-F(x))dx=0$$

Comment: Did you mean to say that the integral equals something else?

Comment: @Zhanxiong, ah, my bad. I meant the value should equal to zero. I revised the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is positive, and can be shown as follows: Make the variable substitution $u = 1 - x$, 
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 (x - 1/2) F(x) (1 - F(x)) d x \\
= & \int_0^1 (1/2 - u)F(1 - u)(1 - F(1 - u)) du \\
= & \int_0^1 (1/2 - u)(1 - F(u))F(u) d u \quad (\text{Apply the symmetric assumption}) \\
=& -\int_0^1 (x - 1/2) F(x) (1 - F(x)) d x.
\end{align}
An rearrangement gives the desired identity.

Comment: If we substitute $u=1-x$, shouldn't it be $du=-dx$? so that it makes the second line be$$\int^1_0(u-1/2)F(1-u)(1-F(1-u))du$$..

Comment: redo your calculation more carefully: $x - 1/2 = (1 - u) - 1/2 = 1/2 - u$. Yes, $du = -dx$, but the upper limit and the lower limit also flipped!

Comment: Oh, that's right. The limits should flip :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.. By substituting $x-\frac{1}{2}=u$ with $dx=du$, we have
$$\int^\frac{1}{2}_{-\frac{1}{2}}uF(u+\frac{1}{2})(1-F(u+\frac{1}{2}))du\\=\int^\frac{1}{2}_{-\frac{1}{2}}uF(\frac{1}{2}+u)F(\frac{1}{2}-u)du.$$
Here, the integrand is an odd function which makes the integral value becomes zero. @Zhanxiong, Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Sorry, there was a stupid typo there.. The second line should be$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}uF(\frac{1}{2}+u)F(\frac{1}{2}-u)du$$

Comment: and it is an odd function because $$-[-uF(\frac{1}{2}-u)F(\frac{1}{2}+u)]=uF(\frac{1}{2}+u)F(\frac{1}{2}-u)]$$

Comment: Please fix the typo in the solution. It looks fine to me now.